# Thinking sphinx attribute from polymorphic association's datetime field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I have a model A associated to model B via INNER JOIN:

```
class A  
  has_many :bees, as: :bable
  scope :bees, -> () {
    joins("INNER JOIN bees AS b ON id = b.bable_id .......")
  }
end

class B
  table_name = "bees"
  belongs_to :bable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I need to filter using B's datetime field (created_at), so I declared a new attribute thus:

```
has bees.created_at, as: :b_created_at
```

The sphinx query statement generated now includes:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(bees.`created_at`) SEPARATOR ',') AS `b_created_at`
```

After indexing, my sphinx index file size exploded.

1. How much is the "GROUP_CONCAT" part of the query causing the problem, and is there a better way to filter by this attribute?
2. How can I debug the indexer and find other causes of the large index file being generated?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the indexer is creating, within the index file, a comma separated list of all created timestamps of all `bees` - as created timestamps are generally unique (!), this indexing is going to create one item for every `bee`.  If you have a lot of `bees` then this is going to be big.

I would be looking at some way to bypass Sphinx for this part of the query if that is possible and get it to add a direct SQL `BETWEEN LowDateTs AND HighDateTs` against the built in `created_at` instead. I hope this is possible - it will definitely be better than using a text index to find it.

Hope this is of some help.

**Edit:**

Speed reading Sphinx' docs:

> [...] WHERE clause. This clause will map both to fulltext query and filters. Comparison operators (=, !=, <, >, <=, >=), IN, AND, NOT, and BETWEEN are all supported and map directly to filters [...]

So the key is to stop it treating the timestamp as a text search and use a `BETWEEN`, which will be vastly more efficient and hopefully stop it trying to use text indexing on this field.

Comment: Sphinx does treat timestamps as integers, and searches using "BETWEEN". The "WHERE" clause would help if I wanted to limit the records to be indexed, but not if I need all the records.

Comment: If you don't want to filter on the timestamp is the problem you're trying to solve that you want to add the timestamp field but you want to tell Sphinx not to index it?

Comment: I do want to filter on the timestamp. Sphinx allows to do 2 things: searching on text fields, and filtering on attributes. I'm doing the second. My question is whether or not that attribute is causing the index file to increase in size.

Comment: Ok.   My misunderstanding.  Short answer - yes.  For n bees index is likely to include n integers +n-1 commas so the index on this field will scale linearly (at about double) with the number of bees.

Comment: If possible in your app, I would look to exclude the timestamp from the indexer and wherever querying the bees data I would filter there by where clause then pass that dataset on to allow Sphinx to use against the other search criteria (or vice versa). This may not be possible or what you want though!